# How can I bind a key to switch to last-pane, or if there are no panes, last-window?

Tags: tmux

If I'm working in a widescreen monitor I like to primarily use two panes and switch between them with `C-a Ca`.

If I'm working on a square monitor I'll use two windows. I'd like to be able to switch between them with `C-a C-a` as well without changing my `tmux.conf`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you always want C-a to

- switch between panes when the active window has more than one pane, and
- switch between windows when the active window has only one pane,

then you can use an `if-shell` that counts the number of panes in the active window to decide between `last-pane` and `last-window`:

```
bind-key C-a if-shell 'test $(tmux list-panes | wc -l) -gt 1' 'last-pane' 'last-window'
```

It will still be “up to you” to rearrange your panes when switching between “wide” and “square” configurations (e.g. via `break-pane` and `join-pane`).

---

In *tmux* 1.8 `if-shell` and `run-shell` do format expansion, so you can simply the shell command a bit:

```
bind-key C-a if-shell 'test #{window_panes} -gt 1' 'last-pane' 'last-window'
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a less cumbersome way to test whether the current window has more than one pane or not. It really should be one of those tmux variables, like `#{pane_count}`, then we can use its `#{?,,}` construct rather than forking out a shell, and another tmux to do IPC, in a pipe, and to `wc -l`. Unfortunately I can't find a good complete list of all tmux variables. I know of at least one undocumented one which is `#{pane_current_command}` which has been handy. **UPDATE** I found it, it's `#{window_panes}` which is "Number of panes in window". perfect

Comment: crap, those conditional thingies might only work for status-string building, not for determining what shell commands to run. Definitely can avoid the pipe to `wc -l` though.

Comment: @StevenLu: *tmux* 1.8 supports format expansions in `if-shell` (and `run-shell`), so you can do this in 1.8: `bind C-a if-shell 'test #{window_panes} -gt 1' last-pane last-window`.

Comment: Really? I can send the window_panes value without calling `tmux` from shell, i.e. the `if-shell` and `shell-run` can interpolate these variables? that'd be really awesome. I did get it working that way though, this would be a good optimization

Comment: If you're in a zoomed pane and you want to switch to the last window rather than last pane in the same window, you can use: `bind C-a if-shell 'test #{window_zoomed_flag} -eq 1 -o #{window_panes} -eq 1' 'last-window' 'last-pane'`

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest the following (adjust 80 to distinguish between your two terminal widths)

```
if-shell '[ "$COLUMNS" -gt 80 ]' 'bind-key C-a "select-window -t :.+"' 'bind-key C-a "next-window"'
```

but I'm either messing up the syntax, or `COLUMNS` isn't set in the relevant `tmux` environment, as the above shell expression always evaluates false for me.

Comment: `if-shell` and `run-shell` are both run in the context of (forked from) the server (not any particular session or client), so they will not have COLUMNS (nor even a tty on std{in,out,err}). You could get the width of the most recently active client with something like this: `tmux list-clients -F '#{client_activity} #{client_width}' | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f`

Comment: IIRC, `$COLUMNS` is a bash variable, not an environment variable; so you'd need to make sure that the enclosing shell was bash while you were running the test. And, even if it were, it would not necessarily be attached to the same pty that the user is looking at (or any pty at all) while pressing the key binding.